# ExpressJS - Middleware Too Many Redirects

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am trying to use two middleware with my `/app` routes that checks for user authentication and then the status of their account. I have both middleware in place, but I am running into an endless redirect in instances where my `req.session.accountStatus` does not equal the conditions I have provided it. In general, I am trying to force the user to only have access to the page being redirected to. Am I using middleware in the wrong way? Is there a better approach?

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/login');
}

function accountStatus(req, res, next) {
    if(req.session.accountStatus == "active" || req.session.accountStatus == "trialing"){
        return next();
    } else {
        //Endless loop. Need to fix
        res.redirect('/app/settings/billing');
    }
}

router.use(require('./site-routes'));
router.use('/app', isLoggedIn, accountStatus, require('./app-routes'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easier to move the middleware to `app-router.js`.

So your main file would only do this:

```
router.use('/app', require('./app-routes'));
```

In `app-routes.js`, you first add the route for the URL that should be "open";

```
router.get('/settings/billing', ...);
```

Followed by the restrictive middleware:

```
router.use(isLoggedIn, accountStatus);
```

Followed by the rest of the routes.

That way, any requests for `/app/settings/billing` don't get passed through the middleware at all, and won't cause a redirect loop.

If `isLoggedIn` is mandatory for *any* route that starts with `/app`, you can use it in a similar way:

```
router.use(isLoggedIn);
router.get('/settings/billing', ...);
router.use(accountStatus);
router.get(...);
```

Comment: This is a great solution! Two quick questions that hopefully you can help answer. 1. `/login` is a route that is defined in my `site-routes.js` file. Despite adding a redirect to this route within the `app-routes.js` accountStatus middleware, it should recognize the route because both files are being attached to `router` via `.use`, correct? 2. Even though I have `/settings/billing` anchored to the `accountStatus` middleware, it is still globally accessible due to it being attached to `router`?

Comment: 1. Yes, a redirect is purely an instruction to the client to "go to" another page. As long as that page exists, it should work. There's no "special handling" performed by Express there. 2. Not sure what you mean by "anchored to the middleware". The `accountStatus` middleware should not get called at all when `/app/settings/billing` gets called (at least, that's what you want, isn't it? Or did I misunderstand the question?).

Comment: Nope it all makes sense. Thank you so much for your help!